# WinAPI Thread unable to write to memory mapped file

Tags: winapi

I am trying to make 2 threads, one that writes to a mapped memory location, and other reading from this location.
So far I have successfully made the threads and the annexed functions to them, but my main problem is that when the first process want to write to the mapped file, I throws me error value 6, meaning a `INVALID_HANDLE_EXCEPTION`, but I can't figure out why would it do that since I have made another program that could write to a mapped location in the same manner. This is my code, and the error is thrown at the `write_in_mapped` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, false, NULL);

int write_in_mapped(HANDLE memoryFile) {
    cout << memoryFile << endl;

    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);

    string message = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    int a = rand() % 10000;
    int b = a * 2;

    message.append(to_string(a)).append(",").append(to_string(b)).append(";");
}

HANDLE mapFile = MapViewOfFile(memoryFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 1024);
if (mapFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    cout << "Unable to map shared memory 1 - error value:" << GetLastError() << endl;
    CloseHandle(memoryFile);
    system("pause");
    return FALSE;
}

if (size(message)) {
    cout << message << endl;
    CopyMemory(mapFile, message.c_str(), strlen(message.c_str()) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    cout << "Succesfully loaded numbers!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Couldn't create numbers!" << endl;
    CloseHandle(mapFile);
    CloseHandle(memoryFile);
    return FALSE;
}

    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);

    cout << "Done write_to_mapped" << endl;

    return 0;
}


int read_from_mapped(TCHAR name[]) {

cout << name << endl;

WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);

HANDLE openFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, name);
if (openFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    cout << "Error at opening mapped memory 2 - error value:" << GetLastError() << endl;
    system("pause");
    return FALSE;
}

LPTSTR mapFile = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(openFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 1024);
if (mapFile == NULL) {
    cout << "Error at mapping memory 3 file - error value:" << GetLastError() << endl;
    CloseHandle(openFile);
    system("pause");
    return FALSE;
}

    string result = string(mapFile).c_str();

    cout << result << endl;

    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);

    return 0;
}

int main() {

    HANDLE process_1, process_2, memoryFile;
    TCHAR name[] = TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");

    memoryFile = CreateFileMapping(0, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 1024, name);

    if (memoryFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        cout << "Error at opening mapped memory area - " << GetLastError() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return FALSE;
}

    process_1 = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)write_in_mapped, &memoryFile, NULL, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(process_1, INFINITE);

    process_2 = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)read_from_mapped, &name, NULL, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(process_2, INFINITE);

   CloseHandle(memoryFile);
   CloseHandle(hMutex);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Besides those errors outlined in the answer, there are more: If you need a cast for the thread routine in your calls to `CreateThread`, you are using the wrong function signature. In this case, you are passing the wrong argument, and missing the calling convention. A more subtle bug is, that you are calling `GetLastError()` too late. You need to call it **immediately** after hitting the condition for which it returns a meaningful value. You are calling it after writing to STDOUT (which may set the thread's last error value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code containing an incredible number of mistakes. all code one big mistake.
`CreateFileMapping` and `OpenFileMapping` return 0 on error but not `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` .
`&memoryFile` and `&name` as parameters to `CreateThread` ?!? when need `memoryFile` and `name` without `&`
you call `CloseHandle(memoryFile);` from `int write_in_mapped(HANDLE memoryFile)` and from `int main()` - so try 2 time close memoryFile, however you got invalid handle in `write_in_mapped` because use `&memoryFile` - so and got `INVALID_HANDLE_EXCEPTION` in `CloseHandle`
`HANDLE mapFile = MapViewOfFile` - what is this ?!? and so on, and so on

**nightmare**

Comment: Thank you, actually you we're right about the `Thread` parameters, but next time make your answer a little bit more easy to understand.